# Wor2vec fine-tuning

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, word2vec

I need to fine-tune my word2vec model. I have two datasets, `data1` and `data2`.

What I did so far is:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(
        data1,
        size=size_v,
        window=size_w,
        min_count=min_c,
        workers=work)
model.train(data1, total_examples=len(data1), epochs=epochs)

model.train(data2, total_examples=len(data2), epochs=epochs)
```

Is this correct? Do I need to store learned weights somewhere?

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244286/fine-tuning-pre-trained-word2vec-google-news/55751018#55751018) and [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/kfujikawa/word2vec-fine-tuning) but I couldn’t understand how it’s done.

Can someone explain to me the steps to follow?

Answer (score 9):

Note you **don't** need to call `train()` with `data1` if you already provided `data1` at the time of model instantiation. The model will have already done its own internal `build_vocab()` and `train()` on the supplied corpus, using the default number of `epochs` (5) if you haven't specified one in the instantiation.

"Fine-tuning" is not a simple process with reliable steps assured to improve the model. It's very error-prone.

In particular, if words in `data2` aren't already known to the model, they'll be ignored. (There's an option to call `build_vocab()` with the parameter `update=True` to expand the known vocabulary, but such words aren't really on full equal footing with earlier words.)

If `data2` includes some words, but not others, only those in `data2` get updated via the additional training – which may essentially pull those words *out* of comparable alignment from other words that only appeared in `data1`. (Only the words trained together, in an interleaved shared training session, will go through the "push-pull" that in the end leaves them in useful arrangments.)

The safest course for incremental training would be to shuffle `data1` and `data2` together, and do the continued training on all the data: so that all words get new interleaved training together.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this correct?

Yes, it is. You need to make sure that data2's words in vocabulary provided by data1. If it isn't the words - that isn't presented in vocabulary - will be lost.

Note that the weights that will be computed by

`model.train(data1, total_examples=len(data1), epochs=epochs)`

and

`model.train(data2, total_examples=len(data2), epochs=epochs)`

**isn't equal to**

`model.train(data1+data2, total_examples=len(data1+data2), epochs=epochs)`

> Do I need to store learned weights somewhere?

No, you don't need to.

But if you want you can save weights as a file so you can use them later.

```
model.save("word2vec.model")
```

And you load them by

```
model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model")
```

([source](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html))

> I need to fine tune my word2vec model.

Note that "Word2vec training is an unsupervised task, there’s no good way to **objectively evaluate the result**. Evaluation **depends** on your **end application**." ([source](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/)) But there's some evaluations that you can look-up [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) (*"How to measure quality of the word vectors"* section)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

When you train `w2v` model with gensim it stores the `vocab` and `index` of each word.
`gensim` uses this info to map a word to its vector.

If you are going to finetune an already existing `w2v` model you need to make sure that your vocab is consistent.

See attached piece of code.

```
import os
import pickle
import numpy as np
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, KeyedVectors
from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec
import operator

os.mkdir("model_dir")

# class EpochSaver(CallbackAny2Vec):
#     '''Callback to save model after each epoch.'''
#     def __init__(self, path_prefix):
#         self.path_prefix = path_prefix
#         self.epoch = 0

#     def on_epoch_end(self, model):
#         list_of_existing_files = os.listdir(".")
#         output_path = 'model_dir/{}_epoch{}.model'.format(self.path_prefix, self.epoch)
#         try:
#             model.save(output_path)
#         except:
#             model.wv.save_word2vec_format('model_dir/model_{}.bin'.format(self.epoch), binary=True)
#         print("number of epochs completed = {}".format(self.epoch))
#         self.epoch += 1
#         list_of_total_files = os.listdir(".")

# saver = EpochSaver("my_finetuned")





# function to load vectors from existing model.
# I am loading glove vectors from a text file, benefit of doing this is that I get complete vocab of glove as well.
# If you are using a previous word2vec model I would recommed save that in txt format.
# In case you decide not to do it, you can tweak the function to get vectors for words in your vocab only.
def load_vectors(token2id, path,  limit=None):
    embed_shape = (len(token2id), 300)
    freqs = np.zeros((len(token2id)), dtype='f')

    vectors = np.zeros(embed_shape, dtype='f')
    i = 0
    with open(path, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
        for o in f:
            token, *vector = o.split(' ')
            token = str.lower(token)
            if len(o) <= 100:
                continue
            if limit is not None and i > limit:
                break
            vectors[token2id[token]] = np.array(vector, 'f')
            i += 1

    return vectors


embedding_name = "glove.840B.300d.txt"
data = "<training data(new line separated tect file)>"

# Dictionary to store a unique id for each token in vocab( in my case vocab contains both my vocab and glove vocab)
token2id = {}

# This dictionary will contain all the words and their frequencies.
vocab_freq_dict = {}

# Populating vocab_freq_dict and token2id from my data.
id_ = 0
training_examples = []
file = open("{}".format(data),'r', encoding="utf-8")
for line in file.readlines():
    words = line.strip().split(" ")
    training_examples.append(words)
    for word in words:
        if word not in vocab_freq_dict:
            vocab_freq_dict.update({word:0})
        vocab_freq_dict[word] += 1
        if word not in token2id:
            token2id.update({word:id_})
            id_ += 1

# Populating vocab_freq_dict and token2id from glove vocab.
max_id = max(token2id.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
max_token_id = token2id[max_id]
with open(embedding_name, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
    for o in f:
        token, *vector = o.split(' ')
        token = str.lower(token)
        if len(o) <= 100:
            continue
        if token not in token2id:
            max_token_id += 1
            token2id.update({token:max_token_id})
            vocab_freq_dict.update({token:1})

with open("vocab_freq_dict","wb") as vocab_file:
    pickle.dump(vocab_freq_dict, vocab_file)
with open("token2id", "wb") as token2id_file:
    pickle.dump(token2id, token2id_file)



# converting vectors to keyedvectors format for gensim
vectors = load_vectors(token2id, embedding_name)
vec = KeyedVectors(300)
vec.add(list(token2id.keys()), vectors, replace=True)

# setting vectors(numpy_array) to None to release memory
vectors = None

params = dict(min_count=1,workers=14,iter=6,size=300)

model = Word2Vec(**params)

# using build from vocab to build the vocab
model.build_vocab_from_freq(vocab_freq_dict)

# using token2id to create idxmap
idxmap = np.array([token2id[w] for w in model.wv.index2entity])

# Setting hidden weights(syn0 = between input layer and hidden layer) = your vectors arranged accoring to ids
model.wv.vectors[:] = vec.vectors[idxmap]

# Setting hidden weights(syn0 = between hidden layer and output layer) = your vectors arranged accoring to ids
model.trainables.syn1neg[:] = vec.vectors[idxmap]


model.train(training_examples, total_examples=len(training_examples), epochs=model.epochs)
output_path = 'model_dir/final_model.model'
model.save(output_path)
```

Comment if you have any doubts.