# Is there still any solution to load the existing Googlenews W2v into gensim and finetune it with additional corpus?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, embedding

In order to fine-tune `word2vec` embeddings in `gensim`, the following piece of code worked with previous versions:

```
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors- 
negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

However, I get the error message that `Word2Vec.load_word2vec` is depracated : 
`DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.`
When I use

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews- 
vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

and then try to fine tune the model with train method as below:

```
model.train((corpus, total_examples=len(corpus2),epochs=10) )
```

I get the following error:

"AttributeError: 'Word2VecKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'train'"

Is there still any solution to load the existing `Googlenews W2V` into `gensim` and fine-tune it with additional corpus?

In response to user:10473854: ignoring warning does not work as the module is already depracated. Also, running Word2Vec with the path for downloaded embedding will make Word2Vec fails. Check this:

```
model = Word2Vec('GoogleNews-vectorsnegative300.bin.gz')
model.wv.vocab

{'/': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7ff6101c3940>,
'a': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7ff6101c39e8>,
'e': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7ff6101c3278>}
```

Comment: I don't believe it ever was directly possible (without a lot of other steps) to keep training a `Word2Vec` model created by `Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format()`. More commentary in my answer to this same question on the gensim discussion list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/XFcVxPqMiOc/9ziDKJKZCAAJ

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a similar thing for GloVe vectors in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56203301/11154976)

Basically starting from GloVe vectors and fine-tuning it on additional corpus using gensim.

In a similar fashion, it can be done for google news vectors as well.

In a gist, you need to set the hidden layers with the old vectors for words in your corpus which are already there in the google new corpus.